# Add items to NSMutableArray and Sort Alphabetically

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, nsmutablearray

I usually parse blog apps by parsing the XML, and sorting to take the pubDate and display newest one first.  To do this I use this when parsing finishes:

```
NSMutableArray *entries = [NSMutableArray array];
            [self parseFeed:doc.rootElement entries:entries];

            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

                for (RSSEntryDirectory *entry in entries) {

                    int insertIdx = [_allEntries indexForInsertingObject:entry sortedUsingBlock:^(id a, id b) {
                        RSSEntryDirectory *entry1 = (RSSEntryDirectory *) a;
                        RSSEntryDirectory *entry2 = (RSSEntryDirectory *) b;
                        return [entry1.articleDate compare:entry2.articleDate];
                    }];

                    [_allEntries insertObject:entry atIndex:insertIdx];
                    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertIdx inSection:0]]
                                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

                }

            }];
```

What I would like to do is simply take the text from the title tag and have it add to the NSMutableArray alphabetically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[NSArray indexForInsertingObject:sortedUsingBlock:]` is an undocumented method, I don't recommend using it.

Here's how to do what you want:

1. put your entries into `_allEntries`
2. sort the array:

```objective-c
    NSArray *sortedEntries = [_allEntries sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {

        RSSEntryDirectory *entry1 = (RSSEntryDirectory *) a;
        RSSEntryDirectory *entry2 = (RSSEntryDirectory *) b;
        return [entry1.articleDate compare:entry2.articleDate];
      }];
```

1. Populate the table view with `sortedEntries`